# How to optimize custom view?

Tags: android, optimization, view

So I defined an custom view based on LinearLayout:

```
    public class AlphabetButton extends LinearLayout{

        private Button alphabetButton;
        private ImageView usersMark;
...     
        public AlphabetButton(Context context) {
            super(context);
            load(context);
        }
...    
        private void load(Context context){
            if(isInEditMode()) 
                return;

            LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.alphabet_button, this, true);

            alphabetButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonAlphabetItem);
            usersMark = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.correctWrongSelectedMark);

            alphabetButton.setTag(usersMark);

            final Typeface chalkFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/myfont.ttf");
            alphabetButton.setTypeface(chalkFont);

        }
```

since app creates about 30 pcs of this view it has a noticeable lag (on weak CPU smartphones it takes about 2-3s) . I also noticed a log output (not mine) like:

```
05-01 16:47:22.224: D/szipinf(10569): Initializing inflate state
05-01 16:47:22.234: D/szipinf(10569): Initializing inflate state
05-01 16:47:22.254: D/szipinf(10569): Initializing inflate state
05-01 16:47:22.264: D/szipinf(10569): Initializing inflate state
05-01 16:47:22.334: D/szipinf(10569): Initializing inflate state
```

and there are about 30 same lines. So I assume that `load(Context context)` method and especially inflating process is the resource of lags. But how to avoid it? How to optimize this view to instantiate it faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can inflate a View and then cache it for future use (i.e. the second time you enter the constructor), because you will get errors like "view already has a parent". However, I don't know if the same holds for the Typeface you inflate.. maybe that one IS reusable.

Furthermore: I don't know if your `R.layout.alphabet_button` contains a lot if images? If that is the case you may want to get rid of a few of those, in favor of xml-generated graphics, like using xml shapes/gradients etc. In my experience, those load a LOT faster. If you cannot get rid of your images, you may at least be able to load those once and then copy them in-memory instead of inflating them each time (so don't put them in your layout.xml, but set them on your ImageView afterwards with methods like `setImageBitmap()` or `setImageDrawable()`.

As always with these kind of caching tricks: be sure to check your app for memory leaks ;-)

Comment: actually the view consists of only one button and one imageview without any picture. its one-time-press buttons. Like if you press the right one app loads the "green" image into the imageview or "red" one otherwise. so there is the only one optimizable thing - its typeface and I already tried not to use it to measure load time and there was no noticeable difference.

Comment: If the layout is really that simple you could always try to just create it in code entirely.. That way you won't have to use the LayoutInflater at all. Stuff like inflating and loading images involves reading data from flash, which is quite slow (even for small files). Creating your hierarchy from code is often faster, but of course for convenience purposes only useful to do when you run into performance issues (like you are now). Give it a try, it's not so hard to new a LinearLayout and add an ImageView on it with the correct LayoutParams. Running out of options here, haha.

Comment: By the way: I always thought the LayoutInflater did implement some caching, so it would only need to read from flash once.. My previous comment won't be as much of a use in that case, only helping you get rid of the first read..